# RMI chat program, need red "error" message

Tags: java, colors, chat

```
public String commando(String username, String channel, String text) throws RemoteException{
        String[] result = text.split(" ", 3);
        if(result[0].equalsIgnoreCase("/join")){
            channel = result[1];
            setChannel(channel);
            joinChannel(username, channel);
        }
        else if(result[0].equalsIgnoreCase("/leave")){
            channel = result[1];
            setChannel(channel);
            leaveChannel(username, channel);
        }
        else if(result[0].equalsIgnoreCase("/whisper")){
            for (int x=2; x<result.length; x++)
            newPrivateMessage(username, result[1], result[x]);
        }
        else if(result[0].equalsIgnoreCase("/exit")){
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else{  
        error(brukernavn, "Wrong!");
        }

        return tekst;
    }
```

I need the error to be in red. This message ("Wrong!") goes to the user that wrote something like /dfdsfsd
I get the message up on the screen, but i cant get it in red. Some idea?

EDIT:

Interference:

```
public interface ChatFront extends Remote {
        void error(String to, String message) throws RemoteException;
}

public interface Klient extends Remote {
        void error(String to, String message) throws RemoteException;
}
```

In the server:

```
class ChatFrontImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements ChatFront {

    private UserDAO b = new UserDAO();
    private Hashtable<String, ArrayList<String>> chanel = new Hashtable<String, ArrayList<String>>();
    private ArrayList<Klient> clients= new ArrayList<Client>();


    public ChatFrontImpl() throws RemoteException {
    }
public void error(String to, String message) throws RemoteException{
        errorTo(to, message);
    }
private void errorTo(String to, String message) throws RemoteException{
        for(Client k: clients){
            if(k.findName().equals(to)){
                k.error(to, message);
            }
        }
    }
```

I have edited some of the names (use Norwegian) so this can be a problem for u, but the program works. The only problem is that i cant get red color on the error message

EDIT 2: Forgot the GUI in client:

```
public class GUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    GUILogikk gl = new GUILogikk(this);

    public void error(String to, String message){
         //chatFelt.setCaretColor(Color.RED);
        chatFelt.append("" + message + "\n");
        chatFelt.setCaretPosition(chatFelt.getText().length());
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the user interface technology?

Comment: Show us the code that styles (colors) your interface, and maybe we can help. Are you using Swing, AWT, SWT, a terminal window?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a console window, you'll have to find functions specific to your operating system to set text color. Those functions vary across operating systems, so either reconsider using a console window or address the issue for each system you plan to use your application on. If you're using something like Swing, you can inspect available text color properties associated with the component you're attempting to draw on (setSelectedTextColor(), etc). More here: [JTextArea](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html)

If you simply want to draw on a Graphics object, you can do the following:

```
g.setColor(Color.RED);
g.drawString("WRONG!", 32, 32); // text, x, y
```

Comment: I'm trying to do something like that in the GUI where the message is written, but when i try this g.setColor(Color.RED); i get cannot find symbol on setColor. Donno what to do. I think its her i have to do the changing. 
  public void feilmelding(String til, String melding){
            //chatFelt.setColor(Color.RED);
            chatFelt.append(melding + "\n");
            chatFelt.setCaretPosition(chatFelt.getText().length());
        }

Comment: Be sure you have a Graphics object 'g' available for writing. I don't know if you can set the color of specific text without designing or using a third-party library.